# Best practice in Python for accessing the value of a k/v pair which may not exist?

Tags: javascript, python

```
function getParams(data) {
    return {
        id: data && data.uuid
    }
}
```

So the above represents a common pattern in Javascript for accessing the items of an object.

What is the most commonly used equivalent practice in Python for accessing items of a dict?

Would it be like so?

```
def getParams(data):
    params = {}
    if data is not None and hasattr(data, "id"):
        params["id"] = data["id"]
    return params
```

If not, what is the best practice? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to access *attributes* (`data.foo`) or *items* (`data['foo']`)?  JavaScript uses the same syntax for these, but they are distinct in Python.

Comment: I want to access items, sorry. Assume `data` is a python dictionary.

Comment: Do you really want to return a dictionary with the same key as you're searching in the original?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a key from a dict without knowing if it's there, you can use the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of dicts.  It returns None (or a specific default value) if the key isn't there:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> print(x.get('a'))
None
>>> print(x.get('a', 'default'))
default
```

Comment: Gotcha. What is the traditional thing to do if I want to check an item in a nested dictionary? i.e. Javascript equivalent would be:

Comment: `data && data.uuid && data.uuid.someAttribute`

Comment: @RyanYu: You can use `get` multiple times, like `data.get('uuid', {}).get('someAttribute', None)`.  But also look around on this site for other people asking similar questions, there are many.

Comment: Although `get` is convenient, be aware that it can be noticeably slower than more verbose code that uses `in`.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean attributes:

```
params['id'] = data.id if data else None
```

If you mean items:

```
params['id'] = data.get('id')
```

In both cases `params['id']` will contain value or `None`.

Comment: What if 'id' does not exist in data? did you check that?

Comment: If 'id' doesn't exist in data, data.get('id') will return None.

Answer (score 0):

Python `dict` is different from `javascript`.

```
def getParams(data):
    params = {}
    if data and 'id' in data.keys():
        params["id"] = data["id"]
    return params
```

Comment: If you want to check, that an item is in a dictionary, use  `'id' in data`. Key checking is a key feature of dicts.

Comment: What Daniel said. `'id' in data.keys()` is wasteful because it has to construct the keys object. That's not so bad in Python 3 because it's a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) that accesses the underlying `dict`; and look-ups on dictviews are fast. But in Python 2 `dict.keys()` has to build a new list object, and lookups on a list involve a slow linear search rather than the fast O(1) lookup that a dictionary or set provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method of `dict`. A default value can also be specified, which could be used if the specified key do not exist.

```
data.get('id', None)
```